# How much of original code is left in modern software products?

Tags: source-code, history

Many of you out there work for large companies that ship well-known software. I was wondering, how much of original code (basically, code that was "v1.0" release) is left in modern massive applications, such as, say, Firefox, Photoshop, Windows, Linux, etc? I'd really prefer first-hand experience and real-world war stories.

Thanks for satisfying my curiosity.

**EDIT**

Turns out there's a degree of misunderstanding. What I'm after is basically as follows: when you [blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html)/[annotate](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-annotate.html) source code, are there any parts or even whole files untouched since the initial 1.0 release.

Comment: some later development might go through major rewrite, or total rewrite (throw away all original codes and code again from zero) or even change to a different platform.

Comment: A river flows down a mountain.  Water evaporates and soaks into the ground.  New water arrives from other streams.  When the river reaches the sea, is it the same river?  How can you tell?  What if no single molecule ever makes the entire journey from mountain-top to sea?  If no molecule is the same, how can we say it's the same river?  And how is this question any more meaningful than the dumb story about the river?

Comment: In case of Firefox, possibly zero - since AFAIK it is a descendant of Netscape 6, which was already a total rewrite of the original Netscape.

Comment: The question starts out OK, but this phrase "I'd really prefer first-hand experience and real-world war stories." is just inviting a list of answers saying "we still have X% of the original code" where X varies from 0 to 100.

Comment: What do you mean by "Blame"?

Comment: @S.Lott Beautiful story, but it has nothing do to with software development. A line of code written 10 years ago is the same line today.

Comment: @ChrisF See my edits.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev: The point is this.  Why ask?  My real-world experience includes two products with 80% the same as 1.0 and 0% the same as 1.0.  That's my experience.  What do you know now that you didn't know before?  What problem do you have that's solved?  How does this help you?

Comment: @S.Lott I'm at a loss here... Curiosity? Isn't it fascinating to know that this Windows 7 Ultimate thing some of us are running still has code dating back to Windows 3.1?

Comment: Firstly your "blame" link points to a Russian site. Secondly I still don't see how these two concepts relate to your question.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev: "Curiosity?" Sorry, that makes little sense to me.  If answer was 17%, what then?  What follows from that observation?

Comment: Oh, this's awesome question.

Comment: -1 This question could be so much more interesting/useful than it is. If you asked for more information, such as project age, language(s) used, number of users, number of revisions, etc. you might be able to draw some conclusions about the average rate of code replacement, stability of code written in different languages, and so on. As it is, you're just asking for a percentage that you can't begin to correlate to anything. It's like asking "How old?" or "What color?" without specifying the thing you're asking about. It's the epitome of 'not useful.'

Comment: @PéterTörök to my understanding Firefox was actually the result of an _additional_ rewrite of Netscape 6.

Comment: You may be interested in [Photoshop version 1.0.1 source code](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/adobe-photoshop-source-code/).

Comment: How about not just original code, but original *buggy* code? There was a famous incident a couple of years ago, where someone discovered a stack overrun error that had been present and undetected in `yacc` for (at least) 33 years: http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20080708155228

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**More than you'd expect** and much older than you'd expect. Even with "total rewrites" and big refactors there are many modules that stay untouched.

Péter suggest that for example you won't find old Netscape code in Firefox. Which is wrong, if you search through source code you'll find quite a few files with disclaimer like:

```
* The Initial Developer of the Original Code is
* Netscape Communications Corporation.
* Portions created by the Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 1994-2000
```

For example in Linux kernel headers you can find things like:

```
include/linux/if_ppp.h: * Copyright (c) 1989 Carnegie Mellon University.
include/linux/quota.h: * Copyright (c) 1982, 1986 Regents of the University of California. 
include/linux/coda.h:          Copyright (c) 1987-1999 Carnegie Mellon University
include/linux/mc146818rtc.h: * derived from Data Sheet, Copyright Motorola 1984 (!).
include/net/slhc_vj.h: * Copyright (c) 1989 Regents of the University of California.
```

Comment: Firefox is full of decade old code, seriously.

Comment: Hey, it still works (probably)

Comment: @Callum Rogers: It works, but not well, and it is slow... A shame how Firefox has fallen like this.

Comment: The MPL requires that the "Initial developer" thing is added, but it doesn't mean that's when the file was last touched. Firefox has plenty of old code, but not if it's slow - code that is slow enough for anyone to notice gets rewritten.

Comment: @Paul: I've checked that many of these files are largely unchanged since initial Hg import of 2007. Don't really know how to get older history (now defunct CVS repo), but I'm pretty sure, large portion of that code wasn't touch in decades.

Comment: @vartac: can't be decades, Netscape only started in 1994 ;) There's no reason to touch working old code. That's the best kind of code! If it's not working (including if it's slow), that's the only time it needs to be touched. (The defunct CVS repo is the canonical repo for code older than the hg import).

Comment: @Paul: well, that almost 2 decades now ;-) Yes, I totally agree that there is no point to change working code.

Comment: @kizzx2 code doesn't rust..

Answer (score 27):

I don't know how much but old code is definitely there but slowly gets removed. E.g. in windows 2008 or vista go to c:\windows\fonts using explorer, right click on left pane and choose "install new font". The dialog box that is shown is from windows 3.1 days (check screenshot). If you see the same in Windows 7 it is now a much better control panel like UI.

[image: Install New Fonts dialog]

Comment: +100 I actually found this myself a few years ago

Comment: Yep, that's... msoOldStyleDialog(?) all right, still supported for legacy programs that are finished and therefore have stayed at 1.0.x. Like a simple file selector. Although in this case it's just a matter of a dialog they missed during the GUI overhaul(s).

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell how old the code at work is.  I can only go back to when it was put in Subversion, and there's a lot that dates back that far.

However, I have a friend who has worked on Microsoft Office code.  A few years ago, he told me he'd removed some SaveA5World calls from it.  That call had a purpose on the old Macintoshes with M680?0 processors, and has served no purpose since Apple went to the PowerPC Macs in the early 90s.

In my observations, any powerful software system that a company relies on was built with technology nobody really wants to use anymore.

Answer (score 2):

"If they did their job exceedingly well from the start, a large part, otherwise a small part."

Strict languages display this trait. Very little has had to change in Nicklaus Wirth's languages, because they were planned with precision. (This has actually changed lately for Delphi, and will change more with the upcoming universal deploy version.)

There is also a flip-side to this, of course. Being deciding that the original code is good enough, such as in the case of Microsoft Windows, or lovely applications like ACDSee, text editors, or the well-known "spirit of Linux" command line applications.

Even though these applications may seem clunky to those who perhaps didn't love them in the first place, they display a well-planned trait as well as a well-defined featureset; even if they don't have bells and whistles, that may be preferred; they do what's on the tin, backward compatibility is great, and are likely to continue to function well in future.

Photoshop would have 90% the same code since 5.0, if you'd go by the featureset. ;P Does it? No. Why? Selling updates. You can't really do more with it today.

The featureset of a file manager, up to the point where it wants to do FTP, web, and cloud is largely the same for any platform for decennia. The only reason such an application still isn't at 1.0 is due to bad planning, whim, an urge to update - and atleast to a small extent the world changing around the application.

The answer is that some gems stay at 1.0 or 1.0.x because the developer has decided on the featureset, completed a bug-free program, and either does not profit from endlessly adding stuff and fixing the bugs in the added stuff, or has moved on to develop more gems.

All else is unlikely to stay anywhere near the code in 1.0. And why shouldn't you rewrite the application if you have a great idea? You should, it's fun to code! :) Except that's not what has taken place in many modern software products. Change for the sake of change (sales) and not motivated by featureset, and to a smaller extent updating to comply with changing platforms, is the order of the day.

And in this soup of interacting pieces of constantly updating software few codebases escape revisions. A few still keep to the dream of foundations and modularizing (and not releasing prematurely), but the vast majority are stuck in the release-fix-update cycle.

Answer (score -2):

Even ostensibly 'cutting edge' systems used for games, like iD Tech and Unreal, would still have a fair bit of 1.0 code in them.